# Prove about cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group $T=\{z \in \Bbb C||z|=1\}$ is cyclic.

I was thinking to prove that the order of every subgroup of $T$ is prime, then they are all cyclic. But I can't. Could somebody give me some hints. Many thanks.

Comment: Don't the $n$th roots of unity form a multiplicative subgroup of order $n$? $n$ need not be prime...

Comment: Perhaps there's some way to show that any group of order $n$ contains the element 
$$e^{(2\pi i)/n} = \cos(2\pi/n) +  i\sin(2 \pi/n)$$

Comment: So if $G$ has order $n$ then it is easy to see that every element of $G$ is an $n$th root of unity.  If you can show the reverse containment, all $n$th roots of unity in $G$, then you would have a primitive $n$th root of unity in your group and you would be done.  I think that would work...although I haven't suggested a way to show the other containment.

Comment: (I'm essentially repeating what @Omnomnomnom is saying)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic.

Comment: @lhf: Not a duplicate, I think, but related to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the order of $G$ is $n$.  Every element of $G$ is an $n$th root of unity.  Since there are $n$ of them, you have all $n$th roots of unity.  Therefore, you have a primitive $n$ th root of unity, say $x$.  The order of $x$ is $n$.  Therefore, $x$ generates your group $G$.  I think this does it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link. It's even better than you might think.
He states

Theorem: Any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is cyclic.

It applies here even though $\mathbb{T}$ is not a field, because $\mathbb{C}$ is.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264530/113214

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication of numbers in $\mathbb{T}$ is a geometric rotation. [A finite group of geometric rotations must be cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148111/proof-that-finite-group-of-rotations-of-plane-is-cyclic).

Diferently said, $\mathbb{T}$ [is isomorphic to the special orthogonal group SO2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group). But [a finite subgroup of SO2 is cyclic](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/MarkH.pdf) (inside the proof ofThm 8.1).